# Can ReactNative runs Windows app simulator on Mac?

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I create RN project with `npx react-native init "ProjectName"` ,and this can be running on iOS and Android simulator. But I want to see it running Windows App on my Mac.
I found this page https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/ , but it looks like here just explain how to build Windows app with WindowsOS.
Is there other side for running Windows app on Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi yes you can download the **Virtual Machine** like `VMware` and install Windows  then you have to configure the react-native-windows setup  your windows in VM  and then you can test it on your mac